# Code takes much longer to execute on a seperate thread in .net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

In my VB.NET program is a time consuming function that gets data and updates the UI at a periodic interval. I moved this function to another thread, but it now takes much longer to execute. Using the stopwatch class, I calculated that when it is part of the main thread, it takes 130 ms, but in the separate thread it takes 542 ms, so that's more than 4 times slower.

My CPU is a Core I5 M520 (2 cores), so I don't now why is it taking so much longer.

I am using the System.Threading.Thread class. I also tried to set the new thread's priority higher, but this had no effect.

Why is the separate thread taking so much longer and is there a way I can speed it up?

Thanks

**The code:**

```
Public Sub update(ByVal temp As Visual)

    SyncLock mUpdateQueue
        If Not mUpdateQueue.Contains(temp) Then
            mUpdateQueue.Enqueue(temp)
        End If
    End SyncLock

    If Not mainThread.IsAlive Then ' moet hierdie beter doen
        mainThread = New Thread(AddressOf DataFetchThread)
        mainThread.Start()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub DataFetchThread()

    Dim s As New Stopwatch()

    s.Start()
    Dim temp As Visual = Nothing
        While mUpdateQueue.Count > 0
            SyncLock mUpdateQueue
                temp = mUpdateQueue.Peek()
            End SyncLock
            mDataCollector.updateV(temp)
            SyncLock mUpdateQueue
                mUpdateQueue.Dequeue()
            End SyncLock
        End While

    s.Stop()
    Debug.WriteLine("thread run time: " & s.ElapsedMilliseconds)

End Sub
```

mDataCollector.updateV(temp): This function get data from a database and plots the points on a picturebox to create a graph. It wouldn't make a lot of sense to add all of the code here.

To ask this question in another way: Is it normal that the second thread takes much longer to execute or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: That's not much to go on - could you post some code that shows what you're doing? Particularly, how are you updating the UI from the worker thread?

Comment: What type is mUpdateQueue? Presuming you're using .NET 4, you could use a `ConcurrentQueue` or a `BlockingCollection` and then you wouldn't need the locks. Also, what does `mDataCollector.updateV()` do?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the other Queue structures. The updateV function gets data located on a server through the use of a dll.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the `mUpdateQueue` variable from multiple threads and using locks to gaurd access to it. This is fine, but using locks has an overhead (to aquire the lock, and during the time that the other threads wait to aquire the lock). This is probably why your new thread is taking longer: it is waiting on the locking.

You could try using the [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) class which may provide faster access to your variables. Just remember that it implements `IDisposable` so you need to call `Dispose` on it when you're done with it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that. If I access variables on the main thread from my new thread without using a lock, could that also slow down the new thread?

Comment: It would (it takes time to create the new thread) but you would never notice it